# How to find likelihood in NLTK

Tags: nltk

http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/comment-page-1/#comment-73511

I am trying to understand NLTK using this link. I cannot understand how the values of feature_probdist and show_most_informative_features are computed.

Esp when the word "best" does not come how the likelihood is computed as  0.077 . I was trying since long back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because it is explaining code from NLTK's source code but not displaying all of it. The [full code is available on NLTK's website](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.classify.naivebayes-pysrc.html#NaiveBayesClassifier.train) (and is also linked to in the article you referenced). These are a field within a method and a method (respectively) of [the NaiveBayesClassifier class within NLTK](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier-class.html). This class is of course using a [Naive Bayes classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_bayes), which is essentially a modification of [Bayes Theorum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) with a strong (naive) assumption that each event is independent.

- `feature_probdist` = "P(fname=fval|label), the probability distribution for feature values, given labels. It is expressed as a dictionary whose keys are (label,fname) pairs and whose values are ProbDistIs over feature values. I.e., P(fname=fval|label) = feature_probdist[label,fname].prob(fval). If a given (label,fname) is not a key in feature_probdist, then it is assumed that the corresponding P(fname=fval|label) is 0 for all values of fval."
- `most_informative features` returns "a list of the 'most informative' features used by this classifier. For the purpose of this function, the informativeness of a feature (fname,fval) is equal to the highest value of P(fname=fval|label), for any label, divided by the lowest value of P(fname=fval|label), for any label:"

  ```
  max[ P(fname=fval|label1) / P(fname=fval|label2) ]
  ```

Check out [the source code for the entire class](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.classify.naivebayes-pysrc.html#NaiveBayesClassifier) if this is still unclear, the article's intent was not to break down how NLTK works under the hood in depth, but rather just to give a basic concept of how to use it.